# Ion-menu-toggle is not closing the menu when navigating to another page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I am pretty new to ionic and app development as a whole but I've tried all of the solutions that I have found and none of them are working, so I thought I would come here and ask myself.
I am using ionic 6.20.9 and all of the dependencies are up to date and are past the recommened version needed for this version of Ionic.

This is my home page html code, I haven't got anything relevent in the .ts files

```
- home.page.html
<ion-menu contentId="main-content" >
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-item routerLink="/home" routerDirection="root" id="active">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="home"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
      <ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-item routerLink="/add-item" routerDirection="root">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Add Item</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
      <ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-item routerLink="/edit-item" routerDirection="root">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="pencil"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Edit Item</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
      <ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-item routerLink="/shopping-list" routerDirection="root">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="basket"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Shopping List</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
      <ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-item routerLink="/map" routerDirection="root">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="map"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Supermarket</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
      <ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-item routerLink="/graph" routerDirection="root">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="bar-chart"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Graph</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
<div class="ion-page" id="main-content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>Welcome {{Username}}!</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content></ion-content>
</div>
```

I have tried creating a closeMenu() function for the pages as well as trying to do with with a service. Giving ion-menu-toggle the auto-hide property hasn't work either.

When clicking on the side menu button all of the links are there and are clickable and lead me to the next page it just that the menu stays open when the links are clicked. The exact behaviour looks like it the menu closes but re-opens when it navigates to the next page, but I'm not sure why this would happen as I haven't called menu.open() anywhere.

If anyone knows of a solution and/or has gone through this before and found a fix please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was working for me. In your **menu.ts** file add this code:

```
  constructor(private menu: MenuController) { }

  closeMenu() {
    this.menu.close();
  }
```

And in your **"menu.html"** under the `</ion-menu>` tag

```
 </ion-menu>

  <ion-router-outlet (ionNavWillChange)="closeMenu()" id="content" main>
</ion-router-outlet>
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this didn't work for me. Nothing changed and I am still getting the same behavior.

Comment: Do you get a error or warning in your google dev console?

Comment: This is al I get
`VM186 vendor.js:13502 Error: ASSERT: can not be animating
    at assert (VM186 vendor.js:9927:11)
    at Menu.updateState (VM228 node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-menu_3_entry_js.js:562:60)
    at Menu.disabledChanged (VM228 node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-menu_3_entry_js.js:117:10)
    at VM186 vendor.js:13057:40
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at setValue (VM186 vendor.js:13054:24)
    at Menu.set [as disabled] (VM186 vendor.js:13092:13)
    at VM186 vendor.js:10577:78
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _setActiveMenu (VM186 vendor.js:10577:54)`